# Page.Load runs every time and takes too long

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an **ASP.Net** page like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Page load code here.  Call Service Layer, which calls Business Layer.
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Button code here
End Sub
```

The code in the `Page_Load` takes too long because it has to connect to lots of different databases (code contained in Business Layer).  What is the best way to cache the page so that the code in `Page_Load` does not run before the click event? The code in `Page_Load` is required as it generates the controls.  `Button1_Click` loops through these controls.

I tend to focus on the Business Layer and Data Layer.  I realize this is probably a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page_Load will ALWAYS run before the click event. You need to familiarize yourself with the [ASP.NET page lifecycle model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms178472.ASPX) and how postbacks work.

Most of the code that runs in Page_Load shouldn't run again on postback, so you use an if statement to check if it's postback. Most loading of controls etc will update the viewstate and so it wont be necessary to reinitialize those on postback.

Comment: The controls are created and values are initialised in the code behind, so I believe your statement is incorrect.  Thanks anyyway.

Comment: +1 mason, just because the controls are created in the page load doesn't necessarily mean they should be...

Comment: @w0051977 You should not typically dynamically create / add controls in the Page_Load function.  Read the page mason linked to, it explains some more about dynamic controls (you should use Init, or even PreInit, that way the ViewState is utilized).

Comment: No w0051977, YOU are incorrect and you really need to read up on the page lifecycle model, as mason rightly suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If the information generated in Page_Load is not needed, you can simply put this line in there, at the top of the method (in C#, but I assume it's similar in VB):

```
If Page.IsPostback Then
    Return
End If
```

If, however, it is needed, then you can use the [`ViewState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Page` object

I would use the method shown in the first example of the link above, and store the results of any calculations you need in there, and then use that to populate controls.

Comment: It is needed though.  As stated in the question: "The code in Page_Load is required as it generates the controls. Button1_Click loops through these controls"

Comment: Note that if the `ViewState` ends up being large, some browsers may be uncooperative with it being stored in one very large HTML hidden input field. You can get around that by making ASP.NET split it into several parts by modifying the `<pages>` section in web.config with, e.g. `<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="4000">`.